# Why is nothing printing out?

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing

I'm relatively new to python so I think this may be an easy question, but it has me confused. Here is my code:

```
# Mike Fitzgibbon CS4250 Project4 implement class diagram
# define the class
class Product:
    # name is the name of the product
    name = None
    # price is how much the product costs
    price = None
    # discount percent is how much the discount is in percentages
    discountPercent = None
    # define the constructor

    def __init__(self, n, p, d):
        # initialize variables
        self.name = n
        self.price = p
        self.discountPercent = d

    # define get discount by returning the discount
    def getDiscountAmount(self):
        return self.discountPercent

    # define discount price by returning the discount percent times the price
    def getDiscountPrice(self):
        return self.discountPercent*self.price

    # define get description by creating description using field variables
    def getDescription(self):
        print("Name: "+self.name)
        print("Price: "+self.price)
        print("Discount: "+self.discountPercent+"%")
        print("Discount price: "+self.getDiscountPrice())
        
        
def __main__():
    p=Product("A",100,90.0)
    print(p.getDescription())
```

Nothing prints out when I run this code. Why? How do I fix this?

Comment: You are not calling the `__main__()` function. You probably intended to write `if __name__ == '__main__':`, instead of defining a function.

Comment: Because nothing calls `__main__()`

Comment: Also of note, `getDescription()` doesn't return anything so `print(p.getDescription())` will always print `None`.

Comment: Ah, thank you, I see the problem now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run your `__main__()` function, you can add to the end of your program:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
   __main__()
```

For printing the values, change `print(p.getDescription())` to `p.getDescription()` because calling the function in class will output the values. BTW, you cannot concatenate int/float with str, so you should convert int/float to string, like `print("Price: "+str(self.price))`

Answer (score 2):

you would need to add;

```
if name == '__main__':
    main()
```

the reason for this is that you have defined the function main, but have not told the computer to run it.